# Jquery append methos

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-append

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="">not here</a></li>
  <li><a href="">append some text only here</a>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="">not here</a></li>
     <li><a href="">not here</a></li>
     <li><a href="">not here</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href=""></a>not here</li>
</ul>
```

I want to append some text only if the li tag has a child ul tag.

Comment: Where you want to add the text?

Comment: none `li` in your example has a `ul` as child

Comment: @steo - actually, one of them do !

Comment: @adeneo sorry, right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to put the text in the `<a>`, so once you find the `<li>`s, look for children which are `<a>`

```
$('li:has(ul)').children('a').text('foobar');
```

Answer (score 2):

Luckily for you, jQuery has a `:has()` selector

```
$('li:has(ul) > a').append('something');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mk9uvq4c/1/)

Comment: I want to add text inside the <a> tag

Comment: @user2333124 - Then just add that? Edited the answer!

Comment: this also adding the text inside tha last <a> tag.Please check the fiddle.

Comment: @user2333124 - If you wanted to ***replace*** the text, say so, don't ask how to ***append*** text !

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li a').text(function(i,v){
  if($(this).parent().children('ul').length){
    return v == 'append some text only here';
  }
});
```

Or using [:has](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

```
$('li:has(ul)').children('a').text('append some text only here');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">not here</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="">append some text only here</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">not here</a></li>
                <li><a href="">not here</a></li>
                <li><a href="">not here</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href=""></a>not here</li>
    </ul>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('li').has('ul').each(function (index) {
                $(this).find('a').html("test");
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```